# Recommend Freeware/OpenSource programs to strip all styling (or selectively)

Tags: html, strip

Longtime lurker, first post. Oh and for the record, I am most definitely *not* a programmer. :)

I'm looking for freeware that will allow me to strip — all, or selectively — the styling in an HTML document. Please recommend your favorites. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HTML Cleaner](https://html-cleaner.com) has an option for what you're looking for.

Comment: Wow what a great link! Thanks Flarp.